# Official Docs of Viewport Width/Height being bad practice in CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, viewport-units

Using the `vw` and `vh` measurements in CSS seems pretty useful sometimes to make Responsive Webpages

However, I see and I have personally used it in places where it would be VERY unusual to use.

I have heard from others that there is "official documentation" stating that VW and VH can be bad practice in any manner, I want to know if that is true or not.

Some Examples of how it could be unusual or bad practice (the bottom one):

```css
/* Background */
.backgroundDiv {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

/* a Top Bar */
.divHeader {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: This question might work better if you were more specific about the "places where it would be VERY unusual to use", and what your concerns are with those usages -- as is this is basically a matter of opinion

Comment: @DanielBeck Yeah, I didnt know, Im talking about using them to measure elements with Text or Images, which can cause many problems on small screens like ios

Comment: Can you specify where “you've heard” this as it is very hard to fact-check heresay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vw` and `vh` are standard units and should work like any other unit. Even if they are used unusually, as long as they are used validly, it is fine to use them like all other units. `vw` and `vh` do have some issues and cross browser problems like other parts of CSS and they can be checked [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). However, viewport units are standardised and it is as safe to use them as it is to use any other units.

In your code above, I would advise not setting the `height` of `.divHeader` using the viewport height; it would be better to set the size of its children elements instead and let them dynamically set the height of the `.divHeader`. `vw` and `vh` are useful when making responsive websites, but there are cases where using percentages or just relying on margins and paddings to dynamically structure your elements for you is better.

Just because `vw` and `vh` can be used does not mean it is always a good idea to use them. They can actually restrict how responsive your website is and it is best to let child elements structure the parent element instead wherever possible to ensure full responsiveness.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i just wasnt sure, I heard somewhere it was bad to use them, happy to hear they are standards.

Comment: `I would advise not setting the height` - why? This is exactly why this question should be closed - it's opinion based. There are many legit reasons to use `vh` units on parent containers.

Comment: @disinfor Its not, I was asking if there was any official talk or documentation or really just proof of Viewport Measurements being Bad Practice in ANY scenario. This can be interpreted as opinionated, but there has been research done here.

Comment: @disinfor using `vh` when setting a header's height can cause the header to become too tall or too short, causing the children elements to be formatted incorrectly. It is best to only use `vh` when necessary and just let the children decide what height the parent should be.

Comment: @Zera yes, thats a better way to put it, Viewport does have its limits, and specifically has some issues functioning on huge screen differences (like PC versus IOS). For example, a background might be Viewport, but the header might be set specifically to 50px

Comment: @Zera that is still opinion based. If you are using `vh` units, you have a reason to do so. There is nothing stopping you from using `vh` on a header (in your example). Yeah, you may want to have an exact pixel value for a header, but depending on what you want to accomplish, there is nothing inherently wrong with using `vh` in that case. The question as stated was "is it bad practice?" The answer is no.

Comment: @disinfor To be completely honest, yes, it is opinion based, but in my own experience I prefer to let elements get sized dynamically. My opinion may differ to yours, as this question is, as you said, primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Zera The system prevents users from asking badly received questions. If they post few questions with no positive score or ones which get closed the system will impose a timeout for this account. It's not really your fault. Don't worry. However, you should not be answering badly written questions. It is usually not worth your effort. They will be closed/deleted and your answer forgotten. Focus on well written questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a bad practice. You may use whatever unit you want if it is handy for you.
What matters is the browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: thanks, as mentioned by zera, they arent bad practice and are standard, thanks for the help you two.